# PYQGIS processing.runalg stops recognising shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, qgis-processing, ubuntu

I am running a processing algorithm `qgis:dissolve` with pyqgis outside QGIS in Ubuntu 16.04 with Qgis 2.18.4

I wrote a python script which takes shapefiles from a folder and runs this with `shpfile` as the input and generate a shapefile in another folder.

```
import sys
import glob
import subprocess
import time
import qgis
from qgis.core import *

def dissolve():
    for shpfile in sorted(glob.glob("/home/user/test/*.shp")):
        filename = shpfile.split("/")[-1]
        f_name = filename.split(".")[0]
        #filename looks like input_001
        num = int(f_name.split("_")[1])
        print filename
        processing.runalg("qgis:dissolve",shpfile,True,"ID","./shp_dissolved_test/"+filename)
        if num % 50 == 0:
            time.sleep(1) 

def main():
    dissolve()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.path.append("/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins")

    # Initialize QGIS Application
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()

    import processing
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
    Processing.initialize()
    Processing.updateAlgsList()

    start_time = time.time()

    main()

    secs = time.time() - start_time
    minutes = secs/60
    print "---" + str(minutes) + "-- min"
```

I have around 600 shapefiles. But the proceesing fails after 200 or so shapefiles and gives error number 4

```
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: /home/user/test/input_197.shp
input_197
ERROR 4: Unable to open /home/user/test/input_197.shx or /home/user/test/input_197.SHX.
ERROR 4: Unable to open /home/user/test/input_197.shx or /home/user/test/input_197.SHX.
ERROR 4: `/home/user/test/input_197.shp' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

But after I rerun it again from that file (input_197) it starts to process again.

Do i need to give some wait time between each processing or is it something else?

Note: After this error I added a `time.sleep(1)` after every 50 shapefile processing but it still fails.

Comment: Have you verified that the shapefiles it fails at aren't corrupted somehow?

Comment: @JohnR The shapefiles are created from QGIS and when I restart the process the shapefiles it could not open works fine again.